# Mongodb slow query on indexed field with different filter values

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to query some data from our collection which has about 45000 documents.

I have indexed status as 1.

status field takes three different values, ra, rc and res.

When I try to query for these different values I get different execution time when I try for "ra"

I am getting 36081 documents while querying for "rc" in 0.125 seconds. while querying for rc such as:

```
db.getCollection('contract').find({"status" :"rc"})
```

But when I run this query for the value of "ra", I get 486  documents in 1.80seconds.

This is weird for me.

What could be causing this difference?

Comment: use .explain("allPlansExecution") to see what it is doing for each query.  Also run each multiple times so you can average out cache access time.

Comment: Interesting, I removed index of status and now it's working very fast.